# JAX-RSの@FormParamでShiftJISを受け取れない

Tags: java, java-ee, jax-rs

JAX-RS（REST Easy）を使ってウェブAPIを作成しています。
あるシステムの`<form>`からデータを受け取るAPIを作成しているのですが、日本語が文字化けしてしまいます。
そのシステムの画面の文字コードはShiftJISです。

```
@Path("test")
public class TestApi {

    @POST
    @Path("hoge")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String hoge(@FormParam("name") name) {
        ...
    }
}
```

上記のようなコードなのですが、`<form>`から "a" という文字を送り、上記のAPI上でEclipseのデバッガからnameの値を見てみると、きちんと"a"が入っています。

しかし "あ" を送ると、" " という空白？文字になってしまいます。
なお、文字列の長さは2であり、`codePointAt`を使って中を覗いてみると

```
name.codePointAt(0)  -> 130
name.codePointAt(1)  -> 160
```

となっています。
まさにこれはShiftJISの「あ」ですので、これをbyte配列に変換すれば、「ShiftJIS文字列 "あ" のbyte配列から文字列を生成する」ということはできますので、一応、問題は解決します。

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[name.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
    bytes[i] = (byte)(name.codePointAt(i));
}

String name2 = new String(bytes, "sjis");
```

ただShiftJISの文字列をJavaで受け取りたいだけなのに、ここまでしなければならないのでしょうか？
他により良い手段というか、なにかアノテーション一発で文字コードを指定できるとか、そういう方法があれば知りたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

サーブレットフィルターでCharacter Encodingを設定する実装を追加すればよかったと思います。

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("Shift_JIS");
```

Tomcatを使用しているのであれば、`web.xml`に以下の定義を追加してみて下さい。

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>Shift_JIS</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```